# How to return System::String handle from function?

Tags: c++-cli

How to return System::String handle from function?

Should I use gcnew or not? For example, which one of the two code examples below are correct?

```
System::String ^ManagedOptimizer::GetLogSolutionEvolution()
{
    return gcnew System::String(myConstCharPointer);
}
```

or this one:

```
System::String ^ManagedOptimizer::GetLogSolutionEvolution()
{
    return System::String(myConstCharPointer);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Microsoft [recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k9s9t975(v=vs.90).aspx) a different constructor than `String::String(signed char* value)`. See the note in the remarks section. It depends on the what is known about the character set and encoding of `myConstCharPointer`. Consider `String::String(SByte*, Int32, Int32, Encoding)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` is a reference type , even if it is immutable. So you must use the "gcnew" version...
See also: [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx)